# How to add canvas to div element dynamically?

Tags: javascript, dom, html5-canvas

Can I add a canvas to body dynamically using java script?
I know how to add a DIV element. There are many examples out there. But how to add a canvas into a DIV element?

```
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.id = 'block';
iDiv.className = 'block';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);


var innerDiv = document.createElement('canvas');
innerDiv.className = 'block-2';


iDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
```

Is the above code correct. Its not working for me. Please suggest me a way to do it.

Comment: It did work with me (I'm using Chrome). Open the Developer Tools window and check your DOM's body element.

Comment: [Code works fine (Firefox)](http://jsfiddle.net/6kL8W/1/)

Comment: it should work , but you should concern adding canvas dimensions ( width and height )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, it works.

Check the rendered HTML or you can simply draw something & see for yourself. ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x8Qf2/))

```
innerDiv.getContext("2d").fillRect(50, 25, 100, 100);
```