# How to add something into a div element

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to make a site that randomizes elements taken from some inputs, and so I don't have a strict amount of inputs I wanted to have a button that generates inputs automatically. My problem is though that the elements that should appear, only either do as text or don't appear at all

```
   <div id="objs">
      <input id="obj_1">
      <input id="obj_2">
    </div>
    <button onclick="addObj();">Add an Object</button>
    <script>
        var i = 2;
     function addObj() {
        i = i+1;
        var existObj = document.getElementById("objs");
        var addedElement = '<input id="obj_' + i + '">';
        //var addedElement = document.createTextNode('<input id="obj_' + i + '">'); 
        //existObj.appendChild(addedElement); 
        //above was test with appending a child which resulted in text outcome
        var newObj = existObj + addedElement;
        existObj = newObj;
        console.log(existObj);
      }
     </script>
```

I've already tried looking up an answer here and elsewhere

( [how to add element within an element in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155551/how-to-add-element-within-an-element-in-html)  and  [How to add canvas to div element dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783283/how-to-add-canvas-to-div-element-dynamically) (these are from StackOverflow))

both attempts resulted in no or text outcome.

Comment: use `innerHTML`: `existObj.innerHTML = addedElement`

Comment: @JosanIracheta: that sadly went the opposite direction it set it so there is only one input

Comment: Instead of trying to create an element via a string, create a real element like `el = document.createElement('input')` and add the id to the newly-created element: `el.id = 'obj_' + i;` Then append `el` to any existing element on your page.

Comment: **To all those who have the same problem, all of the given answers work. It's your choice which to pick.**

Comment: `existObj + addedElement` means `existObj.toString().concat(addedElement)`, which is the worst part.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I got better knowledge now,I updated the answer to be better in line with good JS coding. This is it now:

This will add an element each time you press the button:

```js
let i = 2;

function addObj() {
  i++;
  let container = document.getElementById("objs");
  let newObj = document.createElement("INPUT");
  newObj.setAttribute("id", `obj_${i}`);
  container.appendChild(newObj);
}
```

```html
<div id="objs">
  <input id="obj_1">
  <input id="obj_2">
</div>
<button onclick="addObj();">Add an Object</button>
```

I think you were thinking to complicated.

I don't quite know how JS works in the background. But there is probably a difference between getting an Element and getting it's innerHTML.
Otherwise there wouldn't be a distinction, would it?

Comment: `document.getElementById`...you are missing your t in element

Comment: @Matt Thanks, editing it right away :D Edit: darn, my typing is bad tonight

Comment: Np. Just did a copy and paste and it kept failing until I realized it. Didn't want others to do the same and start down voting you

Comment: @Matt It's probaly my first time being on Stackoverflow for more than 10 minutes, and it's refreshing to know there are nice people on the internet :)

Comment: Thanks to the OP, I love it when untested code works xD

Comment: @Sens even though the other ones worked just as well, yours is the shortest and easiest to work from. Thanks

Comment: I think there is a saying: Keep it short and simple.
I live by it!

Comment: Sorry @Sens I have to downvote your answer. In this case using `.innerHTML` is very bad practice. So I hope nobody else will use your answer.

Comment: @caramba No problem, i'm not too much into JS and it's practice's. So I didn't know. It was just the first and simplest solution I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

```js
function addObj() {
    var existObj = document.getElementById("objs");

    // count those input elements
    // change the selector to '*' or whatever fits your needs
    // if there are also other elements you need to count from id="objs"
    var i = existObj.querySelectorAll('[id^="obj_"]').length + 1; 

    var newElement = document.createElement('input');
        newElement.id = 'obj_' + i;

    existObj.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

```html
<div id="objs">
  <input id="obj_1">
  <input id="obj_2">
</div>
<button onclick="addObj();">Add an Object</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You said

> above was test with appending a child which resulted in text outcome

And this is logic because you are using `document.createTextNode`.
However, you should use instead `document.createElement` .

```
   <script>
     var i = 2;
     function addObj() {
        i = i+1;
        var existObj = document.getElementById("objs");
        var addedElement = document.createElement("input");
        addedElement.id = 'obj_' + i;
        existObj.appendChild(addedElement); 
        var newObj = existObj + addedElement;
        existObj = newObj;
        console.log(existObj);
      }
     </script>
```